# Finite groups of prime power order containing an abelian maximal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group containing an abelian maximal subgroup. Then it is a well-known result that $|G:Z(G)|=p|G'|$. If in addition $G$ is of nilpotent class 2, then $|G:Z(G)|\leq p^{r+1}$, where $|Z(G)|=p^r$.
My question is: Is there better bound for $|G:Z(G)|$ in this case (class 2 and containing an abelian maximal subgroup)?

Thanks for any comment or answer.

Comment: No, it's easy to achieve this bound, say for $p$ odd, with $G$ of exponent $p$, with elements $x_0,\dots,x_r,y_1,\dots,y_r$ with $[x_0,x_i]=y_i$ and all other pairs commuting.

Comment: For $p=2$: start from the dihedral group $D$ of order $8$ with $s,t$, $s^2=t^4=1$, $sts^{-1}=t^{-1}$, $t$ of order 4. Consider the direct power $D^r$ (of order $2^{3r}$), write the elements $s,t$ of the $i$-th copy as $s_i,t_i$. Consider the subgroup generated by $u=s_1\dots s_r$ and all the $t_i$. Then it has order $2^{2r+1}$ and works in the same fashion.

Comment: Another way to look at this is. Form the semidirect product of an elementary Abelian group $A$ of order $p^{2n}$ with a cyclic group $C$ of order $p$, where each indecomposable summand of $A$ as $C$-module has order $p^{2}$. Then $AC$ has order $p^{2n+1}$ and its center has order $p^{n}$, while $AC$ has class two.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments.